# Is there a difference between assigning a value to a variable using the equal operator or using curly braces?

Tags: c++

I saw a code where a programmer used curly braces to initialize a variable

```
int var{ 5 };
```

instead of using the assignment operator

```
int var = 5;
```

I know assigning a value to lhs variable using curly braces is a C++11 syntax. Is there any difference between using the two?

Thank you for replies.

Comment: One is list initialization and one is not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are different kinds of initialization:

```
T a{b};   // list initialization
T a = b;  // copy initialization
T a(b);   // direct initialization
```

There is no difference for `int`s but there can definitely be differences for other types. For instance, copy initialization might fail if your constructor is `explicit`, whereas the other two would succeed. List initialization disallows narrowing conversions, but for the other two those are fine.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no difference in the two for integers. The `{}` syntax was made to(however, not limited to, because it is also used for `initializer_list`) prevent programmers from triggering http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse, and so instead of `std::vector<int> v()` to initialize v you write `std::vector<int> v{};`.

The `{}` has different behaviours depending on the usage, it can be a call to constructor, a initializer list and even a list of values to initialize members of user-defined class in order of definition.

Example of the last:

```
class Q{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    float f;
};

int main()
{
    Q q{2, 5, 3.25f};
}
```